# Copper mean free path dependence on temperature

Tags: temperature, mean-free-path

I'm doing simulations of copper, where the temperature can reach up to ~1300 K.

Some calculations depend on the mean free path (MFP) of copper. The only value I've found for it is 39nm and it's always accompanied with the clause of "at room temperature".

Can anybody tell me (or provide some references), how does the MFP depend on temperature?

Copper's resistivity dependence on temperature is known to me, can that be used to derive the mean free path dependence in the following way?

So we got the conductivity $\sigma(T)$ and that can be related to the relaxation time as

$\sigma = \frac{n e^{2}}{m} \tau$

And the relation between the mean free path and relaxation time is  $\Lambda = v_F \tau$, where $v_F$ is the Fermi velocity (is this an approximation?).

Thus we get

$\Lambda(T) = \frac{v_F m}{n e^{2}} \sigma(T)$

Is this a valid way of finding the dependence of the mean free path of copper on temperature?